# Windows 10 - Show all users on lockscreen

Tags: windows-10, user-accounts, lock-screen, workgroup

I am connected to a workgroup in windows 10 pro 64bit. On the lockscreen it only shows logged on users, the last used user and other users. How do I display all users on my lockscreen?

Comment: Your anwser is here: https://www.top-password.com/blog/make-windows-10-8-show-all-user-accounts-on-login-screen/ P.S.: Google is your friend

Answer (score 1):

According to [this link](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/9134-do-not-display-user-name-sign-screen-windows-10-a.html) you can set a local policy for this or reg key:

1. Open *secpol.msc* and navigate to *Local Policies*, *Security Options* and then find *Interactive Logon: Do not display last user name* and set it to *Disabled*
2. Open *regedit* and navigate to *HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System* and change the DWORD value of the key *dontdisplaylastusername* to 1

Option 1 worked for me at least.